# php Values Java Byte Array

Tags: java, php

I am a bit confiused about the "pack" / "unpack" php Function, so i need the php Equivalent to the following Java Code

```
....
byte[] TempByte = {1, (byte)0x01};
...
```

php:

```
?
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what that Java code does, but it looks equivalent to something like this:

```
$tempByte = "\x01\x01";
```

"Byte arrays" are essentially strings in PHP, or rather "strings" are essentially byte arrays in PHP. You can even access this "byte array" using the array offset syntax:

```
echo bin2hex($tempByte[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no real php equivalent, as php is *loosely typed*, and not has a `byte[]` type.

The code that resembles your java code most is:

```
$TempByte = array(1, chr(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted initializes a byte array consisting of two elements, [bytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Since PHP is [weakly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_typing) you cannot get an exact equivalent of this code - which can be seen from the list of [PHP types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.php).

Both languages have arrays, so we re good here, but PHP doesn't have byte.

In Java a byte is defined as an signed 8-bit value ranging from -128 to 127 (inclusive).

The closest thing to that PHP would be an [integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), but:

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

So, my suggestion would be (for a 32bit platform):

```
$TempByte = array(0x0001 & 1, 0x0001 & 1);
```